# Show index and not the archive for "Dog Custom Post" with default slug

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, page-template, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

When creating a Custom Post, in my case with the name `dogs` and slug `dogs`, at the url `www.example.com/dogs` Wordpress shows by default the archive page if `has_archive` is set to true

I don't want to deactivate the archive functionality for this CPT, because I would like to have an archive to show animals no more available at the shelter and manually archived.

How can I take advantage of the clean url `www.example.com/dogs` for showing the index loop? And showing the archive in another location like `www.example.com/archive/dogs`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just need to set `has_archive` to a string instead of `true` with the desired slug, in my case `archive/dogs`.

Then, create a page with the `dogs` slug and set the desired template to it.